# Mount a capacitor on a connector without any solder

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, connector

I am looking for a specific connector that I can solder / press-fit in my PCB and mount a capacitor on the connector without any solder such that I can easily remove or replace the capacitor without desoldering. 
I have one option to use a press-fit capacitor. But I am open to any other suggestion for the connectors.

AEC 100uF, with 2 leads, cylindrical, axial [mouser.ca/datasheet/2/212/KEM_A4011_PEG124-1104316.pdf](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/212/KEM_A4011_PEG124-1104316.pdf)

Comment: What kind of capacitor?

Comment: Aluminum Electrolytic capacitor 100uF

Comment: Is this lead-less? Cylindrical? Size? Radial mount? Axial?

Comment: @Maodude 100 uF AECs come in a variety of mounting packages. It would be helpful to specify the package rather than the electrical specifications.

Comment: AEC 100uF, with 2 leads, cylindrical, axial https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/212/KEM_A4011_PEG124-1104316.pdf

Comment: [Edit] the details into your question and add a picture so that your readers don't have to follow links to understand your question. Don't bury important details in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this thread.

Answer (score 17):

You might consider using screw terminals.  Such as shown below. No solder required.  Just a small screw driver.  It's reliable and durable. And you can try different parts if you need to.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

For a tool-free solution, use a common female header.

[image: Female header]
(Image from [sparkfun.com](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14321))

The male leads of the header go in your PCB. Insert the capacitor leads in the holes of the header and they are pinched in place.

You can choose one that spans enough width for your capacitor. (0.1"/2.54mm pitch shown above). You may want a header with 3+ pins so as to be wide enough.

Comment: I like this idea the best, kind of like a breadboard, cheap and readily available

Comment: Caution: thin component leads may not be gripped by a socket intended for relatively thick header pins. A better choice is sockets specifically intended for component leads (SIP sockets).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I think this will not hold the capacitor enough as I need my module to pass the Seismic test.

Comment: @Maodude - That was not (and is still not) declared in your question.

Answer (score 4):

The Wago 733 or 734 series might also be interesting to you. Cable and capacitor can easily released by inserting a small screwdriver into the upper slot. Note: The connector shown in the picture is the one attached on the cable side. If you plug out the cable, the capacitor comes out with the connector and loses contact to the PCB.

[image: WAGO 733-105 Connector]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. +1 for Wago connectors, I love them.

Answer (score 1):

These would be physically larger than most, but if you go to an electronics supplier that carries hundreds of thousands of different capacitors, they will have both "snap in" and "screw terminal" capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

Turned pin Sil sockets. Cut to length required. An alternative is the crystal sockets although their pin connections can be larger in diameter leading to intermittent contact with the capacitor leads. Some force is required to connect up and on some capacitors the leads require trimming to equal length.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Robert Neill's suggestion, there are single-contact sockets similar to turned pins available in a variety of sizes to accommodate different pin diameters.  They can be had in both SMT and PTH varieties.  Some even allow the mating pin to pass straight through the socket and the board, although these are only available in through-hole for obvious reasons.

There are also a variety of spring-loaded tabs that are usually intended to make electrical contact with a housing for EMC purposes, but some of them are shaped such that they can accept a pin.

Finally, you haven't mentioned if this is meant to be easily removable or not, but for a permanent connection there are single wire-to-board IDC terminals, that are designed to be soldered into the board and have an insulated wire pressed into them.  The terminal displaces the insulation and makes contact with the wire inside.  You might be able to locate a part that is designed for solid conductor wire and matches the lead diameter of your capacitor well enough to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with one of this.
It's easy to solder on the board. After that insert or remove a cap is really practical.
I think you should consider also if you can, get a radial cap, this connector suits best on that kind of capacitor.
Hope it helps!

https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/preci-dip/323-87-102-41-001101/323-87-102-41-001101-ND/4099478

[image: dip_connector]